# Problem with updating nested array of object in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, backend

I am trying to update a field in nested array object, but the field is not getting updated.

[image]

I need to update the comment field and I am using the below query to update it, using mongoose,

```
let updateComment = await StoryComment.update({ _id: this.req.body.commentId, 'comments.reply.userId': currentUser, 'comments.reply._id': this.req.body.replyId }, { $set:{ 'reply.$.comment': replyData } }, { new: true, 'safe': true, 'upsert': true });
```

can anyone help me to fix this issue, it looks right but its not getting updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following, this might meet your requirement

```
   let updateComment = await StoryComment.updateOne(
      {
        _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(this.req.body.commentId), 
      },
      {
        $set:{ 
          "comments.reply.$[el].comment": replyData 
          
        }
      },
      {
        arrayFilters:[{
          "el._id":mongoose.Types.ObjectId(this.req.body.replyId) 
        }],
        new: true
      }
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
{ $set:{ 'comments.reply.$.comment': replyData } }
```

Comment: Is this doing insert all the time?

Comment: its always updating a specific one although the reply._id is different

Comment: I guess it's always updating the first reply. You can check with `find` what document are you getting back as you are running on `comments` collection that will always return `comment' document only

Comment: let me try the find option